# Trigger to handle Multi Insert Statements

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, triggers

I have [two](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=45a31c5ed38057c455c6682a12ce913f) table **Stocks** and **Purchases**

```
CREATE TABLE Stocks
(
  id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  itemId int NOT NULL,
  qty int  NOT NULL,
  status NVarChar(50) NOT NULL,
)


CREATE TABLE Purchases
(
  id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  itemId int NOT NULL,
  suppId int NOT NULL,
  qty int  NOT NULL,
  Date NVarChar(50) NOT NULL,
  status NVarChar(50) NOT NULL,
)
```

Here is what I want do:

ON Inserting Multiple Records into **Purchases** table, I want Create a Trigger that Iterates over each Record Inserted and Check itemId FROM the **Stocks** Table

UPDATE TheQuantity(qty in this case) of each itemId found AND INSERT into the **Stocks** Table if itemId isn't found

I have tried several ways, in fact I have been struggling with it since yesterday.

[this Post](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=45a31c5ed38057c455c6682a12ce913f) was the closest one I have seen but could figure out what is going on, seems like it's only Updating already existing records

> Here is what I have tried so far, I meanthe closest I came

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[trPurchaseInsert] on [dbo].[Purchases] FOR 
  INSERT
 AS
DECLARE @id int;
DECLARE @itemId int;
DECLARE @status NVarChar(50) = 'available';

    SELECT @itemId=i.ItemId FROM INSERTED i
 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Stocks WHERE itemId=@itemId)
 BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

     DECLARE @itemIdUpdate int;
     DECLARE @qty int;

    SELECT @qty=[quantity], @itemIdUpdate=[itemId] FROM INSERTED i 
    
    UPDATE Stocks SET qty=qty+@qty WHERE itemId=@itemIdUpdate
  END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO Stocks SELECT [itemId], [id], [quantity], @status 
    FROM INSERTED i
 END
```

this works fine in a single Insert but doesn't work when multiple records are inserted into the Purchase Table at once

The above Trigger Updates the first itemId only and doesn't update the rest or even insert new ones if one itemid is found

The Goal here is to Update in stock items if itemid is found and Insert if itemId isn't found

For Further Details [see this SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=45a31c5ed38057c455c6682a12ce913f). It contains Tables & what I have tried with commented details

I have seen several comments advising to use **set base operations with joins** but couldn't figure a direction

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Please don't put your attempts in an off-site resource, include them in the question itself in a code block/fence. You can include a link to a fiddle, but it should compliment the post, not be mandatory to consume.

Comment: You do NOT want "a Trigger that Iterates over each Record Inserted and Check itemId FROM the Stocks Table". Putting loops in a cursor is a recipe for disaster. Just don't do it. This can and should be a set based operation. You would do this by first doing an update joining your table with inserted. Then you would do an insert using a left join where the new value doesn't match.

Comment: @Larnu I Edit and added Code sample.

Comment: `Date NVarChar(50) NOT NULL,` Start over and use the appropriate datatype - which is DATE. Then define the purpose of itemId in Stocks and how it differs from id. Where are your foreign keys?

Comment: @SeanLange could you please create a sample or a direction, I have seen several comments on similar questions advising to use set based and joins but could't really get the direction

Comment: Take a look at the answer by Charlieface. That is an excellent example of doing this as a set based approach instead of an iterative one. I also agree with the suggestion that doing this in a trigger is maybe not the best idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your trigger is fatally flawed.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) It does not take into account multiple rows being inserted, it also doesn't deal with updates and deletes.

Instead you should use this:

- Note how `inserted` and `deleted` are both used. `deleted.qty` is subtracted.
- The whole thing is grouped up by `itemId` and then the difference is applied to `Stocks`.
- Since you also want to insert, you need to use `MERGE`. Alternatively, you can have separate joined `UPDATE` and `INSERT...WHERE NOT EXISTS` statements.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trPurchaseInsert
ON dbo.Purchases
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

MERGE Stocks s
USING (
    SELECT
      diff.ItemId,
      qty = SUM(diff.qty)
    FROM (
        SELECT
          i.ItemId,
          i.qty
        FROM inserted i
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
          d.ItemId,
          -d.qty
        FROM deleted d
    ) diff
    GROUP BY
      diff.ItemId
) diff
ON diff.ItemId = s.ItemId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (itemId, qty, status)
  VALUES (diff.itemId, diff.qty, 'available')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    qty += diff.qty;
```

**I must say, I would not implement this with triggers at all.**

It's best not to denormalize such data into another table. If you need to query it, you can just do it on the fly from the `Purchase` table. Use a view if you want, and even index it.

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.vTotalStock
WITH SCHEMABINDING   -- an indexed view must be schema-bound
AS
SELECT
  p.ItemId,
  qty = SUM(p.qty),
  count = COUNT_BIG(*)  -- must always include COUNT_BIG if aggregating and indexing
FROM dbo.Purchases p
GROUP BY
  p.ItemId;
```

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UX ON vTotalStock (ItemId)
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=72e81baf7c4cb13aa0d41613a82c5d4e)

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate, with a little twist it worked as per required. I also configured it for Sales. AND YUP, Read the article and I have to think about using variables in Triggers next time