# How to write trigger to process batch update query with condition for each row that get update?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a table `[Latest_Entry_Value]` like this, which store latest data of each entry and get update every 10 min or so.

| Entry_Name | Entry_Group | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| B | 1 | 22 |
| C | 2 | 15 |

and I need a trigger to update or insert this value to table `[Entry_Value_Daily_Log]`, which store last value of the day of each entry like this

| Entry_Name | Entry_Group | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2202-08-17 | 25 |
| B | 1 | 2202-08-17 | 24 |
| C | 2 | 2202-08-17 | 11 |
| A | 1 | 2202-08-18 | 10 |
| B | 1 | 2202-08-18 | 22 |
| C | 2 | 2202-08-18 | 15 |

I have try an update trigger on `[Latest_Entry_Value]` with `if` condition to do update or insert into `[Entry_Value_Daily_Log]` which work fine if I'm update `[Latest_Entry_Value]` one row at a time.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Update_Entry_Value_Daily_Log] 
   ON  [dbo].[Latest_Entry_Value] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @Entry_Name VARCHAR(20);
   DECLARE @Entry_Group VARCHAR(20);
   DECLARE @Value INT;
   
   SELECT 
      @Entry_Name = Entry_Name,
      @Entry_Group = Entry_Group,
      @Value = Value
   FROM INSERTED;

   -- Check [Entry_Value_Daily_Log] if entry log date already exist
   IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Entry_Value_Daily_Log] WHERE [Entry_Name] = @Entry_Name AND [Date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
   BEGIN
      -- row existed, do update
      UPDATE [dbo].[Entry_Value_Daily_Log]
      SET [Value] = @Value
      WHERE [Entry_Name] = @Entry_Name AND [Date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
      -- new day, do insert
      INSERT INTO [dbo].[Entry_Value_Daily_Log]
      ([Entry_Name],[Entry_Group],[Date],[Value])
      VALUES
      (@Entry_Name, @Entry_Group, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), @Value)
   END
ENDฺ
```

But when I do batch update to `[Latest_Entry_Value]` like

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Latest_Entry_Value]
SET [Value] = [Value] + 2
WHERE [Entry_Group] = 1
```

which should effect 2 row in `[Latest_Entry_Value]`. only the first row got triggered and update or insert to `[Entry_Value_Daily_Log]`. Which, from my understanding after google, happen because trigger is suppose to be only one transaction. so how should I write the trigger to solve this.

Comment: Your trigger is flawed. By doing `@Entry_Name = Entry_Name` etc you are assuming that the updates only affects single row and `INSERTED` only contains one row. This is not true. You should insert into `Entry_Value_Daily_Log` by selecting from `INSERTED`

Comment: Is MERGE not an option for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger to handle Multi Insert Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73377972/trigger-to-handle-multi-insert-statements)

Comment: Aside: You're going to have fun when multiple calls to `GetDate()` return different dates. Consider starting with `declare @Today as Date = GetDate();` and then using `@Today` as needed throughout the code.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trigger will fire only once when more than one row is updated at once, not one time for each updated row.
So all you need to do in your trigger is update all matching rows, and insert all others.
You can do that direct by joining on the inserted table.
See the example below, you might need to adjust some things but it should get you in the right direction.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Update_Entry_Value_Daily_Log] 
   ON  [dbo].[Latest_Entry_Value] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   declare @date date = getdate();

   -- update existing
   UPDATE l
   SET    l.Value = i.Value
   from   dbo.Entry_Value_Daily_Log l
     inner join inserted i on l.Entry_Name = i.Entry_Name
                          and l.Entry_Group = i.Entry_Group
                          and i.Date = @date


   -- new day, do insert
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Entry_Value_Daily_Log]
     (Entry_Name, Entry_Group, Date, Value)
   select i.Entry_Name, i.Entry_Group, i.Date, i.Value
   from inserted i
   where not exists (select 1 
                     from   dbo.Entry_Value_Daily_Log l 
                     where  i.Entry_Name = l.Entry_Name
                     and    i.Entry_Group = l.Entry_Group
                     and    i.Date = @date
                    )

END
```

You could also use [Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in stead of doing update and insert

Comment: I'm trying to update table2 by creating trigger on table1 but some its not working with this code

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla Can you give some more information ? It would be best if you would create a new question for this problem and explain in detail what is not working

Comment: I have got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou all, I've try both update and insert, and merge solution and they both work. so I'm just gonna also post merge solution here in addition to the update and insert from @GuidoG.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Update_Entry_Value_Daily_Log] 
   ON  [dbo].[Latest_Entry_Value] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @date date = getdate();

   MERGE [dbo].[Entry_Value_Daily_Log] AS l
   USING INSERTED AS i
   ON i.Entry_Name = l.Entry_Name
   and l.Date = @date
   WHEN MATCHED
   THEN UPDATE
   SET
      l.Value = i.Value
   WHEN NOT MATCHED
   THEN INSERT (
      Entry_Name,
      Entry_Group,
      Date,
      Value)
   VALUES (
      i.Entry_Name,
      i.Entry_Group,
      @date,
      i.Value);
END
```